# How to Make an dynamic App Name?

Tags: android, ios, rename

I want to know if it's possible to achieve this: If I'm Pablo (the user) who downloaded the app "XXX", I'll want the app to be shown as "PabloXXX" or "WhateverXXX" on the device.

Do you think is possible? Either in Android or iOS...

Comment: It is not possible in Android, as the app name needs to be a string resource, which is not editable at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible neither in Android nor iOS.
As mentioned by CommonsWare those are settings inside configuration files which are not editable at runtime.